# why does this code segment System.out.print('a'+' '); print 129?

Tags: java

why does this code segment System.out.print('a'+' '); print 129?

```
void main()
    {
       System.out.print('a'+' ');
    }
```

Comment: `Unicode` values. `97 + 32 = 129`

Comment: because `char` is a numeric value

Comment: Unicode values. @Uma

Answer (score 3):

If the left operand is a string, the `+` operator concatenates the right operand, returning a new string.

If the left operand is a numeric value, the `+` operator performs mathematical addition.

In Java, character constants, as well as `char` variables, are considered numeric.

The value for `'a'` is 97. The value for `' '` is 32. 97 + 32 is 129.